# htaccess exclude a page from rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?pirate-punk.com(/)?.*$     [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]+\.[a-z0-9]+)$ http://www.pirate-punk.com/dl.php?f=$1 [R,NC,L]

Options +Indexes
```

This htaccess will redirect all incoming traffic to another page if they come from a different domain.

I would like to exclude all index.php pages from this rule so my visitors can still visit an index.php page even if they come from outside of the domain

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a condition which excludes anything that ends with a `/` or `/index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(index\.php)?$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?pirate-punk.com(/)?.*$     [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]+\.[a-z0-9]+)$ http://www.pirate-punk.com/dl.php?f=$1 [R,NC,L]
```